# Django rest - convert field into a list?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Textfield in my model which stores dictionaries, I would like to convert this field into a dictionary if possible in a rest serializer.

at the moment the field returns the dictionary but backslashes all the quotes, it is possible to convert the strings into a nested list of dicts?

Thanks

api currently returns below:

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "hostname": "WAN-EDGE",
        "timestamp": "2019-04-12T11:34:36.654521",
        "routing_table": "[{\"route\": \"0.0.0.0\", \"subnet_mask\": \"0.0.0.0\", \"next_hop\": \"172.16.66.193\"}, {\"route\": \"10.10.21.0\", \"subnet_mask\": \"255.255.255.0\", \"next_hop\": \"172.16.67.146\"}, {\"route\": \"10.22.0.0\", \"subnet_mask\": \"255.255.0.0\", \"next_hop\": \"172.18.1.5\"}, {\"route\": \"10.31.0.0\", \"subnet_mask\": \"255.255.0.0\", \"next_hop\": \"172.16.67.146\"},...]"
    },...
}
```

desired result a nested list of dicts

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "hostname": "WAN-EDGE",
        "timestamp": "2019-04-12T11:34:36.654521",
        "routing_table": [
                        {
                            "route": "0.0.0.0",
                            "subnet_mask": "0.0.0.0",
                            "next_hop": "172.16.66.193"
                        },
                        {
                            "route": "10.10.21.0",
                            "subnet_mask": "255.255.255.0",
                            "next_hop": "172.16.67.146"
                        },
                        {
                            "route": "10.22.0.0",
                            "subnet_mask": "255.255.0.0",
                            "next_hop": "172.18.1.5"
                        },
                        {
                            "route": "10.31.0.0",
                            "subnet_mask": "255.255.0.0",
                            "next_hop": "172.16.67.146"
                        },...
                    ]
    },...
}
```

Current serialiser:

```
class RoutingTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hostname = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='device.hostname',
    )
    rt = serializers.JSONField(
        source='routing_table'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceData
        fields = ('id','hostname','timestamp','rt')
```

Comment: Why don't you use JSONField instead of TextField in your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need [**`serializers.JSONField()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield)

---

**Update-1**
You could also try with [**`SerializerMethodField()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as

```
import json


class RoutingTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hostname = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='device.hostname', )
    rt = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='routing_table', read_only=True)

    def get_routing_table(self, instance):
        return json.loads(instance.routing_table)

    class Meta:
        model = DeviceData
        fields = ('id', 'hostname', 'timestamp', 'rt')
```

Comment: I tried this but it still outputs the same    rt = serializers.JSONField(
        source='routing_table'
    )

Comment: ive added my current serializer

Comment: I assumed get_routing_table was supposed to be get_rt from an error I got so swapped that, now I get JSONDecodeError at /api/rt_status/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Are you sure that you have a valid JSON? (I tried it and succeeded)